# Is it possible to group products in Opencart?

Tags: php, opencart, shopping-cart

I have searched for this, but couldn't find a solution I required. 
What I need is:

I have a set of product. I need to show it a single set so that when customer clicks on the set, he must be able to see all the products under that set in a single screen. Customer must be able to add the quantity for individual products under that set in the single screen itself.

Is there a possible way to do that in Opencart. Any advices ?

Comment: **Yes, it is possible** if You posses enough of programming skills to implement it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the opencart's options and developed extensions to achieve that.

You can add options under catalog>>options

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Grouped Product" extension id 5359

Comment: Best explain your answer